# Rails 4 rendering partials (undefined local variable or method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I am trying to pass two local variables to my partial but I am getting this undefined local variable or method `row' for #<#:0x00000105d7f3b0> when using it in the partial.

Render

```
<%= f.fields_for :menu_items do |builder| %>
<%= render partial: 'menu_item_fields', locals: {f: builder, row: f.options[:child_index]} %>
<% end %>`
```

Partial

```
<a href="#" data-target="item-<%= f.options[:child_index].to_s + "-" + row.to_s %>" class="item-field"><%= f.object.title %></a>
```

Comment: Prpovide the line of code in which the error occouring?

Comment: I did. Its labeled "Partial"

Comment: I am using nested attributes and need a builder for the nested items

Comment: Sorry, I just had a "duh" moment.  I meant to say since :menu_items is a collection and you are rendering a partial each time [rendering a collection may be better suited for this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections) as it executes once for every item in the collection.

Comment: I will look into that but I still am stuck with the same problem

Comment: I'm having trouble with passing local variables too, perhaps our problems are related. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940837/passing-local-variables-down-partial-heirarchy-in-rails-4-for-ransack-associatio/

Answer (score 1):

Change this code

```
<a href="#" data-target="item-<%= f.options[:child_index].to_s + "-" + row.to_s %>" class="item-field"><%= f.object.title %></a>
```

as follows:

```
<a href="#" data-target="item-<%= f.options[:child_index].to_s + '-' + row.to_s %>" class="item-field"><%= f.object.title %></a>
```

Comment: I tried that and I have tried just doing this <%= row %> and it still gives the same error. Great catch though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be :

```
{ f: builder, row: builder.options[:child_index] }
```

Oops, I misread your code on my mobile phone. Does your code work correctly if you don't call it using a partial?

Comment: If that was the case I would have no reason to pass row in the first place.

Comment: Right, what happens if you only pass f along? Like: parent_form: f. And then in your partial call parent_form.options[:child_index] ?

Comment: Same thing. It says undefined for the parent_form. The problem occurs when I have more than one local variable

Comment: Passing multiple values through locals should be no problem. You could test this by only passing parent_form and again call parent_form.options[:child_index]. It should still fail.